# Htmlunit fail with a http response without header

Tags: java, http, http-headers, htmlunit

i have a problem with htmlunit.

I make a request to a page that does not return the header along with the reply. Imake the following request:

```
        ......   
        this.webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setPopupBlockerEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setPopupBlockerEnabled(false);
        webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://applicationtoanalize.com/login.cgi");
        .......
```

In this case the exception that is raised is the following.

```
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:187)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:193)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1402)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1321)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:394)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:315)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:466)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:448)
        at com.myapp.api.net.WebSiteSelettra.login(WebSiteSelettra.java:26)
        at com.myapp.api.test.NetTest.testHomePage(NetTest.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:149)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        ... 57 more
```

The problem seems to be due to the fact that the server does not return an http header.
Unfortunately I have no control over the server (it's from third parties) and I can't modify the application on the server. I can only request the pages I need.

I can not understand what could be the solution to be able to load the page via htmlunit and perform searches (via xpath inside it). For example, normal browsers have no problem loading the page and returning the contents. Is there a way to do the same with HTMLunit?

Thanks to all

Comment: Check if there is some http proxy configured in your system that might make your real browsers work with no issues. If yes, you will have to configure your client to work though a proxy as well.

Comment: @AlexeyR. there are no proxies configured in my system. From what I understand, browsers are lenient with respect to this type of problem